# How to debug a binary with the relative path in argv[0]?

Tags: linux, gdb

I have a binary `test` that I want to debug with gdb. As you can see `pwd` is `/tmp`:

```
$ gdb
(gdb) file test
Reading symbols from /tmp/test...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) pwd
Working directory /tmp
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/test
```

or

```
$ pwd
/tmp
$ gdb test
Reading symbols from /tmp/test...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
The target architecture is assumed to be i386
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/test
```

The problem is that gdb executes the file with the absolut path `/tmp/test` instead of the realtiv path `test`. Which means `argv[0]="/tmp/test"`.

How can I make gdb execute the file with the relativ path (`argv[0]="test"`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out myself with a cool trick I didn't know before - `set exec-wrapper`

```
$ cat wrapper.sh
#!/bin/bash
p="test"
exec -a "$p" "$@"
```

and in gdb

```
(gdb) set exec-wrapper ./wrapper.sh
```

This way you can set the `argv[0]` to whatever you want.

source: https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2013-05/msg00049.html